# Call a function inside a custom data-attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a current CMS we are working in, I need to call functions within a custom data-attribute. Is it possible to call the contents of a data attribute as a function to run like below? Simple example:

Set

```
 <button data-function="alert('hello world')">Run Function</button>
```

Run

```
$('button').attr('function');
```

I believe the above is just getting the contents and not actually executing anything when written.

Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds like a horrible way to have to call JavaScript.

Comment: Are the functions preknown?

Comment: Yes the function are known. They are Google Event Tracking functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a `Function` from the data attribute:

```
// create
var funcStr = $('button').data('function');
var f = new Function(funcStr);

// invoke
f();
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: Only slightly less *evil* than *eval*, but yes :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I think it's essentially the same evilness.

Comment: @Barmar: How about "more explicit evilness"?

Comment: Evilness is in the attempt to invoke arbitrary script. But, at least `Function` gives you some more control.

Comment: @Barmar It's easier to prevent global access from `new Function` than `eval`. You can also prepend wrapper code to hide unwanted variables, or (more practically) modify the scope or `this` of the function to call it in the context of some event or object.

Comment: @haim770 These all worked but yours seemed the safest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is another approach if the function is known.

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('button').click(function() {
         var functionObject = JSON.parse($('button').attr('data-function'));
         window[functionObject.name].apply(window, functionObject.arguments);
       });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-function='{"name": "alert", "arguments" : ["hello world"]}'>Run Function</button>
```

It parses the JSON string from the `data-function` attribute. Call the function provided by `name` using the window object (eliminating `eval`) and passes the arguments (inside an array) to the function using `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute the code, you will have to call `eval`. You also need to use the full name of the attribute, or use `.data()`.

```
eval($('button').attr('data-function'));
```

or

```
eval($('button').data('function');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function.

```
eval($('button').attr('data-function'));
```